# wp_list_comments() with a custom comments form?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a child them from the 'Responsive' theme. I customized the comments form in page.php, removing the 'website' text box using the technique described [here](http://chipcullen.com/altering-the-comment-form-in-wordpress/).

The original page.php in the theme has:

```
<?php responsive_entry_after(); ?>
<?php responsive_comments_before(); ?>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php responsive_comments_after(); ?>
```

I replaced that with my custom code:

```
<?php responsive_entry_after(); ?>
<?php responsive_comments_before(); ?>
<?php $fields = array(
          <snipped for clarity; this part works>                             
                          );

 $commentParams = array(
    'title_reply' => 'Leave a Comment.' ,
    'comment_notes_before' => 'My custom text.',
    'comment_notes_after' => 'More custom text.',
    'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', $fields)
    );

comment_form($commentParams); ?>
<?php responsive_comments_after(); ?>
```

I found that my custom form works as expected, but comments are no longer listed on the page. I added a call to wp_list_comments(), but still don't get the list of comments.

How can I display the comments and use a custom comment form? I believe the need to customize the form precludes the use of comments_template(), does it not?

Many thanks!

Comment: are you sure that, comments are being stored that is comments are found in the admin panel, comment section with all fields what you have added.

Comment: Yes. When I revert to the original Responsive theme, the comments are listed.